# Cpanel: после создания 2-го домена создается поддомен главному домену

Tags: seo

после создания дополнительного домена additional.com он будет доступен как поддомен main.com, т.е. введя в адресную строку браузера additional.com или additional.main.com вы увидите одну и ту же страницу. 
Вопрос - является ли это проблемой для поисковиков т.е. одинаковом содержимое, которое доступно по различным URL. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дублирующее содержание может создать проблемы для вашего сайта. Возможное решение: использование атрибута **rel=canonical** для указания предпочтения/главенства ваших веб-страниц. **[Справка Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)**. Основное требование для дублирующего содержания - это применение без умысла манипулировать поисковым рангом или обманное привлечение пользователей на веб-сайт. Например: мобильная версия веб-сайта или версия для печати. В **[этой документации Гугл](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls)** описано, как помечать дублирующее содержание для мобильной версии веб-сайта. Справка Гугл **[Повторяющийся контент](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=ru)**.